# Firestore rules hashing returns identity

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my rule, I want to ensure that the `data.id` field is the hash of the `doc` `id`. The following is not working.

```
function hashGood(a, b) {
  let x = hashing.sha256(a);
  return x == b;
}

match /users/{userId} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null && hashGood(userId, request.resource.data.id);
}
```

I have also tried `hashing.sha256(a.toUtf8()).toBase64()` and variations thereof.

When I try to create `/users/B` in the 'Rules Playground', it shows `x == "B"` . But `x` should be the hash of "B", not equal to "B".

What I am doing wrong?

Edit: I am using `rules_version = '2';`

Answer (score 3):

`hashing.sha256(a).toHexString()` worked for me.

Though I would like to still understand why
`let x = hashing.sha256(a)` prints `x=<value of a>`

Comment: *firebaser here* It turns out this behavior in the rules playground is broken, and your code will correctly work in production. Also see the answer by one of our engineers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72263557