# Invalid hashing in Firebase Cloud Storage Rules Playground

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security, firebase-console

I am testing [hashing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.hashing) in the rules playground:

This returns "CRexOpCRkV1UtjNvRZCVOczkUrNmGyHzhkGKJXiDswo=", the correct hash of the string "SECRET" :

```
let expected = hashing.sha256("SECRET");
```

But this returns "SECRETpath/to/the/file.mp4", the argument itself instead of its hash:

```
let expected = hashing.sha256("SECRET" + request.resource.name);
```

Is it a bug in the rules playground?
Can hashing functions be used on dynamic values or is it intentionally prevented?

The strange rules playground behavior has been mentioned here before, this time with Firestore security rules: [Firestore rules hashing returns identity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70369023/6016470)

Comment: Your title says you're asking about Storage rules, but I don't see a `hashing` object defined there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage. Are you sure this isn't for Firestore?

Comment: Yes indeed ```hashing``` is only listed for Firestore rules in the doc, however as you can see, it is actually defined and somehow works, so I assumed it is just missing from the doc.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the execution engine different for Storage and Firestore? I would find it surprising that they don't provide the same functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebaser here!

There are a few issues at play here. I think the primary source of confusion is that the [`hashing.sha256` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.hashing#.sha256) returns a [`rules.Bytes`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Bytes) type. It appears that the Rules Playground in the Firebase Console incorrectly shows a string value when debugging the bytes type, but that is unrelated to behavior in production. **For example, this Rule will always deny:**

```
allow write: if hashing.sha256("SECRET" + request.resource.name) ==
    "SECRET" + request.resource.name;
```

**To get the behavior you're looking for**, you need to use one of the conversion functions for the `rules.Bytes` type. Based on your question, you'll probably want the [`toBase64()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Bytes#toBase64) function, but [`toHexString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Bytes#toHexString) is also an option. If you try these functions in your Rules, the Playground should start behaving correctly and the Rules will work as expected in production as well. **So to put it all together**, you'd write:

```
let expected = hashing.sha256("SECRET" + request.resource.name).toBase64();
```

For example, the rules listed below would allow you to upload a file called "foo/bar" (as `Gqot1HkcleDFQ5770UsfmKDKQxt_-Jp4DRkTNmXL9m4=` is the Base64 SHA-256 hash of "SECRETfoo/bar")

```
allow write: if hashing.sha256('SECRET' + request.resource.name).toBase64() ==
    "Gqot1HkcleDFQ5770UsfmKDKQxt_-Jp4DRkTNmXL9m4=";
```

I hope this helps clear things up! Separately we will look into addressing the wrong debugging output in the Playground

Comment: Thank you, it works as a charm! I was aware of the necessary bytes to string conversion, but I may have messed up my rule's code as I was destabilized by the debug output. Thank you for your help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

After trying with emulators and the deployed app, it seems that hashing.sha256 does not work on dynamic data in any environment. The behavior is consistent, so **I filed a feature request** to add this function to storage security rules. This would be nice because it would allow passing signed data to the security rule for each file (for ex: an upload authorization obtained via a Cloud Function)

As of now, the workaround that I imagine is putting data in user custom token (or custom claims), so I can pass signed data to the security rule. It is not ideal because I need to re-sign with custom token for every file upload.